# How to get to child properties in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to write trigger which will change property "Offset" when mouse is over the button. When i try like this:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="button">
                <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonTheme" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Stroke="Silver" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle>
                <Rectangle x:Name="HighLight" Opacity="1.0">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.8">
                            <GradientStop x:Name="Flower" Color="#AAFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Content= "{TemplateBinding Property = ContentControl.Content}" />
                 </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="Flower" Property="Offset" Value="1" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

It returns "Child with name "Flower" is not found in Visual Tree". Is there a way to change that property?

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says what's wrong. The `GradientStop` is not part of the visual tree, it's not a Visual. And I think this is some kind of limit in XAML, it would be better to easily do what you did.

To stick with the code you have now, we can only use a hacky solution in which we bind the `Offset` of the GradientStop to some ***known*** element's  property. (***known*** element here means it is accessible via the `TargetName` set for `Setter`). The only property I think is suitable here is the `Tag` property. Then you can use `Setter` to set the Tag property of the known element instead. Here is the code following that idea:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Button">
        <Grid x:Name="button">                
            <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonTheme" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Stroke="Silver" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle x:Name="HighLight" Opacity="1.0" Tag="1">
                <Rectangle.Resources>
                   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="proxy" Value="{Binding ElementName=HighLight}"/>
                </Rectangle.Resources>
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.8">
                        <GradientStop x:Name="Flower" Color="#AAFFFFFF" 
                                      Offset="{Binding Value.Tag, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
            <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Content= "{TemplateBinding Property = ContentControl.Content}" />
             </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="HighLight" Property="Tag" Value="0" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Note that I set the `Tag` to `0` for testing purpose (the Offset should be different before and after mouse is over), you can set it to any you want.

The non-hacky way is using `VisualStateManager`, you can do something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Button">
    <Grid x:Name="button">                
        <Rectangle x:Name="ButtonTheme" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10" Stroke="Silver" StrokeThickness="3" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle x:Name="HighLight" Opacity="1.0" Tag="1">               
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush Center="0.5,0.8">
                    <GradientStop x:Name="Flower" Color="#AAFFFFFF" 
                                  Offset="1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#00FFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content= "{TemplateBinding Property = ContentControl.Content}" />
         <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
             <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                   <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HighLight" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.GradientStops[0].Offset" 
                    To="0" Duration="0"/>
                   </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
             </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>        
</ControlTemplate>
```

You use the path `Fill.GradientStops[0].Offset` in the DoubleAnimation targeting the `HighLight`, so it's important to know the index of the  GradientStop whose Offset you want to change on mouse over.